# Even tiles wide pathfinding on square based tilemaps?

Tags: path-finding, tilemap

By editing my **A* algorithm** as such that:

- a tile is valid if all of its neighbours are valid (checking this N-1 deep)

I can find N wide paths, where **N is odd**, and my unit just follow the "center" tiles.

But what if my unit is **even tiles wide?**

Yes, I generate a 2 tiles wide path, and then traverse it with an offset, so my unit will walk on the overlapping edge between the 2 tiles. (maybe there is a better solution, suggestions are welcome)

**But how do I find even wide paths?**

(Or my whole approach is bad?)

Answer (score 1):

instead of pathfinding on the centers of the tiles, pathfind along the corners and edges of the tiles.

A corner is valid if all the neighbouring tiles are valid according to your existing algorithm(n-1)

Answer (score 0):

Draw an NxN square with the tile in the corner.  The tile is only valid if every tile in the square is valid.